# Ubuntu 12.04.1amd64bit tls installation problem

Tags: system-installation

When i finish installing Ubuntu 12.04.1amd 64bits TLS alongside with windows 8 on my laptop it was not showing ubuntu at the start-up boot but it just boot to windows 8. how do i get the ubuntu i installed?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. A lot of people have that problem with Ubuntu. What happened is you did a legacy install even though your computer is booting in UEFI mode. To fix this, follow these instructions:

1. Boot into your Ubuntu LiveCD
2. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a Terminal session
3. Type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair && sudo boot-repair` into Terminal, then type <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Choose the Recommended Repair
5. Follow the instructions you are given.
6. Reboot when done.
7. Profit! You now have a working dual-boot setup!